# how do I code multiple boxes in one box and have them next to each other without having them vertical?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so the boxes are next to each other, but when I add another box it goes to the bottom. I'm fairly new to html and css, how would you do that? If you could code that part for me and explain it, I'd be really grateful.

Image:
http://i61.tinypic.com/9lj0ox.png

```
<div id="leftside">
    <div id="portrait"></div>
    <div id="leftbox"><b>About Me</b><p>test</p></div>
    <style>
        #leftside {
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 0px;
        top: 125px;
        width: 220px;
        height: 485px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #portrait {
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        background:  url(http://i861.photobucket.com/albums/ab179/treeskywind/profile/kidosmall2_zps57444730.png    );
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        }
        #leftbox {
        height: 230px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: #6855A7;
        color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        text-align: justified;
        overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</div>

<div id="rightside">
    <div id="box1"><b>Links</b></div>
    <div id="rightbox"><b>My Interests</b></div>
    <div id="box2">test</div>
    <style>
        #rightside {
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 0px;
        top: 125px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 485px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 280px;
        }
        #box1 {
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 160px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #6855A7;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        }
        #rightbox {
        height: 260px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: #6855A7;
        color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        text-align: justified;
        overflow: auto;
        }
        #box2 {
        width: 200px;
        height: 160px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #6855A7;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        margin-left: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

btw put your  above your page html!!